# Add JFace Key Scheme Programmatically

Tags: java, jface

I thought about repurposing `org.eclipse.jface.bindings.Scheme` to store key bindings on a per user base:

```
    String userName = "Bob";
    BindingManager bindingManager = ((BindingService) PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getService(IBindingService.class)).getBindingManager();
    Scheme scheme = bindingManager.getScheme(userName);
    scheme.define(userName, "Scheme for user " + userName, DEFAULT_SCHEME);
    bindingManager.setActiveScheme(scheme);
```

Which works well for some moments, but whenever the schemes get loaded from the preferences (e.g. via `CommandPersistence#reRead`) only the schemes defined in the *plugin.xml* will be read and everything else gets discarded.

Especially this method of the class `BindingService` is a problem:

```
public final void savePreferences(final Scheme activeScheme,
        final Binding[] bindings) throws IOException {
    // store everything in preferences, then read everything
    // -> custom schemes get removed
    BindingPersistence.write(activeScheme, bindings);
    // now the removed (undefined) scheme gets set
    bindingManager.setActiveScheme(activeScheme);
    bindingManager.setBindings(bindings);
}
```

Since I can't really register all users via *plugin.xml*, how can I register schemes programmatically?

Comment: `BindingService` is an internal class, you should not be using it.

Comment: @greg-449 How do I get the `BindingManager` without the cast?

Comment: @greg-449 And I tested the code with a freshly created `BindingManager` - it's the same problem:  `savePreferences` cannot set a custom scheme, only one defined in the _plugin.xml_.

Comment: Also that code for `BindingService.savePreferences` is for Eclipse 3.x, in Eclipse 4.x the method is completely different and stores the bindings in a different place. There is no defined API to access the `BindingManager`.

Comment: @greg-449 Yes, we're using the last stable version of Eclipse (3.7), we can't risk E4 just yet. And the problem is not the `BindingManager`, it's that `BindingService` calls `undefine()` on custom schemes and then tries to set them as the active scheme.

Comment: My point is if you keep using internal classes you are going to have huge problems when you try to move to Eclipse 4 as large numbers of internal classes have been completely rewritten.

Comment: @greg-449 We don't use internal classes at all. I added the cast as an example on how to get the `BindingManager`. Our code uses a freshly created one. And judging by what is said in Java User Groups, we are switching to JavaFX before E4, so no worries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a "solution", I just re-implemented the scheme for our use case:

```
String userName = "Bob";
String keyBindings = MyPlugin.getDefault().getPreferenceStore().getString("keyBindings." + userName);
PlatformUI.getPreferenceStore().setValue(PlatformUI.PLUGIN_ID + ".commands", keyBindings);
```

This triggers `CommandPersistence#reRead` as well, but since I don't have my custom scheme this time, it doesn't fail. Now the management of our different schemes is **our** problem, but at least that way it works.